# Pasting a value into outlook email body

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code to copy excel values and now what I want to do is paste that range into my email body. I am unsure of how to paste it. Thank you all for your time. I have tried to create another "msg" with selection.Paste but it errors out.

```
Sub Send_Emails()



Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim msg1 As String
Dim msg2 As String
Dim msg3 As String
Dim msg4 As String
Dim msg5 As String
msg1 = "Hi" & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value & "," & " " & "<br>" & "<br>"
msg2 = " I am reaching out to schedule"
msg3 = Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Offset(0, 1).Select
   Selection.Copy
msg4 = " What dates and times work best for you or others?"



With OutMail
  .To = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
  .CC = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
  .Subject = "Update Request"
  .HTMLbody = msg1 & msg2 & msg3.Selection.Paste & msg4
  .Display
End With

On Error Resume Next:
OutMail = Nothing
OutApp = Nothing






End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR appologies, I am new to the community, what do you mean?

Comment: @BRolf Please tell us which error you get (message) and in which line.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ When I write "Selection.Paste" under msg3 I get the error message "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier"

Comment: Google RonDeBruin he has a page with loads of examples on Excel VBA to Outlook

Comment: @RichardTompsett thank you for the tip. I am looking through his page now

Answer (score 0):

Well this line

```
msg3 = Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Offset(0, 1).Select
```

doesn't make sense. You need to set the `.Value` to the variable

```
msg3 = Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Offset(0, 1).Value
```

then you don't need to copy `Selection.Copy` remove that.

And you don't need to paste:

```
.HTMLbody = msg1 & msg2 & msg3.Selection.Paste & msg4
```

instead just use the variable

```
.HTMLbody = msg1 & msg2 & msg3 & msg4
```

I recommend to read some good tutorial on how to use variables and values from cells to learn some basic programming techniques.

Comment: @PEH Thank you very much for the help. First do you know of any good tutorials I can access? Second when I try to do the.Value I get an error message "Type mismatch" 


    msg3 = Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 
    0)).Offset(0, 1).Value

Comment: I will try and define msg3 as something else, and will report back

Comment: @BRolf no of course you can only put the value of **one** cell into **one** variable. You cannot put a range of values into one variable. You probably just asked the wrong question and I think you are looking for something different: See https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm

Comment: @PEH appologies if I asked the wrong question. I have a range of cells withwords in them that I am trying to copy and paste into an email. Not one cell. I will investigate rondebruin. Thank you for the help today